# what's causing tensorflow error "Attempted to pad to a smaller size than the input element" error when trying to train using custom dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to use tensorflow to create a model trained off my own dataset

my dataset has 2 inputs and 2 outputs,
the first input is an image with shape(320, 180, 1),
the second input is a bool with shape(),
the first output is float32 with shape(2,),
and the second output is an int with shape()

training always fails immediately giving the following error

2 root error(s) found.
(0) DATA_LOSS:  Attempted to pad to a smaller size than the input element.
[[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
[[IteratorGetNext/_6]]
(1) DATA_LOSS:  Attempted to pad to a smaller size than the input element.
[[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_1655]

I understand what padding is, but I have no idea why tensorflow would be padding the data here, much less why it would try to pad to a smaller size

I used the tensforflow_datasets builder to make the dataset using the following code to parse the data

```
features=tfds.features.FeaturesDict({
        # These are the features of your dataset like images, labels ...
        'image': tfds.features.Image(shape=(320, 180, 1)),
        'position': tfds.features.Tensor(shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32),
        'action': tfds.features.Scalar(dtype=np.int8),
        'hint': tfds.features.Scalar(dtype=np.bool_),
    }),
supervised_keys=(('image', 'hint'), ('position', 'action')),
```

...

```
    for row in csv.DictReader(csvData):
    fileName=row['fileName']
    yield fileName, {
        'image': path+fileName,
        'position' : [np.float32(row['Xpos']), np.float32(row['Ypos'])],
        'action' : np.int8(row['action']),
        'hint' : tfds.core.utils.bool_utils.parse_bool(row['hint']),
    }
```

...

```
dataset_train=tfds.load('my_dataset', split='all', batch_size=64, as_supervised=True)

for example in dataset_train.take(1):
    pass
```

this will throw the same error. It seems tensorflow is completely unable to iterate through the dataset

I've already made sure there's no corrupted data, every image is exactly 320 pixels wide and 180 pixels tall with 8 bit color depth.

Comment: We also have no idea why Tensorflow would pad here, because you did not provide any code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've edited to help clarify the issue